# How to use Bluetooth Low Energy badge for localization?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, indoor-positioning-system, trilateration

I know, this question has been asked a lot of times. Until yesterday i thought that the answer was "yes, it is possible but you can not obtain an accurate result of your position". My idea is to take a BLE badge in my hand and with other 4 devices, positioned on the ceiling, obtain my current position using the trilateration. After weeks of resarch, i concluded that this method could not be as accurate as i'd like it to be, so i went over. 
Now, what about this video? [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0vJBbQA9_M) by [Loopd](https://loopd.com/).

They use bluetooth badges, but how they obtain these results? 
Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

The results of Bluetooth LE indoor location can be quite accurate, but it requires some processing of the raw signals rather than simple triangulation. Essentially you weight different beacons differently in your position calculation based on how far away they are and filter to smooth the result.

There is a working example as open source at http://vor.space/